# VPS as a load balancer?

Tags: vps, load-balancing

What are the advantages and disadvantages of using a VPS as a load balancer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few advantages:

- cheap or free depending on your current setup
- familiar operating system so managing/monitoring will come fairly easy
- performance can be decent for moderate load levels
- leverages existing virtualization environment, and any HA therein

A few disadvantages:

- likely no commercial support
- for high-load environments, VPSes won't hold a candle to "real" hardware-based load balancers
- VPSes will be less stable than hardware load balancers